# ESP32 unable to detect interrupt

Tags: esp32

The code below is suppose to detect a pulse from a rain gauge. It is working in esp8266 but not in esp32 nodemcu. The logic seems fine I suppose I did something wrong while define the pin?

```
const int interruptPin = 18; 
volatile boolean  interrupt = false; 
const int led = 2 ;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), ISR, FALLING); 
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(led, LOW); 
}
 
void loop() {
  if (interrupt == true) { 
    Serial.println("An interrupt occurred");
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);     
    interrupt = false;
  }
  delay(1000);
}


 
IRAM_ATTR void ISR () {                  
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH); 
  interrupt = true;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the question. Could you add some details to describe how you debug this and what is an expected result?